# How to Access images and Videos from a specific local folder in UWP Javascript application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, uwp

Access images and Videos from a specific local folder in UWP Javascript application

We want to create a slider using the images and videos from a specific folder from the device.

Means, As the UWP application starts it should take the content(Assets) from the Specific folder in Uwp javascript application.
Any way to do this.?
for example: we want to get the content from d:/My project data.

```css
<style>
        body {
            font: normal 0.9em Arial;
            color: #ddd;
            background: #FFFFFF;
        }

        header {
            display: block;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
        }

            header a, header span {
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 4px 8px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                border: 2px solid #000;
                background: #DDD;
                color: #000;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-align: center;
                height: 20px;
            }

            header span {
                background: white;
            }

        a {
            color: #7fa9fe;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo 4: jQuery Slideshow</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="css/thumbs2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/thumbnail-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/thumbnail-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="thumbnail-slider.js"></script>
    <body>
    <!--start-->
    <div style="padding:260px 0;background:#FFFFFF;">
        <div id="thumbnail-slider">
            <div class="inner">
               
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/1.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/2.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/3.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/4.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/5.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/6.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/7.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/8.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/9.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/10.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/11.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/2.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/3.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/4.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/5.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/6.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/7.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/8.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/9.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/10.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/11.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <video width="350" height="350" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" display="inline-block;">
                            <source src="img/mcvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                        </video>
                    <li>
                        <video width="260" height="260" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" display="inline-block;">
                            <source src="img/SampleVideo_640x360_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                        </video>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <video width="260" height="260" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" display="inline-block;">
                            <source src="img/small.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                        </video>
                    </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
       

    </div>
    <!--end-->
    <div style="max-width:700px;margin:0 auto 80px;background:#333;">
        

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working code snippet. The question is now too broad

Comment: hello SuperDJ i added some html and css code into it i hope u will understand the question now thanks

Comment: Have you checked [`broadFileSystemAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) capability?

Comment: i have added                                                                                              <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities> and also <b>package</b>:- <Package
    xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
    xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
    xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
    IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp wincap rescap">

Comment: but i am getting error

Comment: To access files even when `broadFileSystemAccess` is applied, you need to use `StorageFile` APIs to reach them.

Comment: can you please show me how to use StorageFile API to Access Images and Videos Access images and Videos from a specific local folder in UWP Javascript application.

Comment: @AnkitSoni Does it work?

Comment: no it is not working

Comment: @AnkitSoni I have edit the answer please check.

Comment: @AnkitSoni I have checked your capability If you have not add `wincap`, please remove it from  `IgnorableNamespaces`.

Comment: yes i removed it

Comment: @AnkitSoni  Does the following code  work in your side?

Answer (score 0):

> can you please show me how to use StorageFile API to Access Images and Videos Access images and

After you added `broadFileSystemAccess` capability, you could use Windows Storage Api to access specific folder such as `D` disk. Then convent the image file to `Base64` data for displaying. You could refer the following.

```
function ConverToBase64(file, success) {
    file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.read).then(function (stream) {
        var inputStream = stream.getInputStreamAt(0);
        var reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(inputStream);
        var size = stream.size;
        if (size > 0) {
            reader.loadAsync(size).then(function () {
                var buffer = reader.readBuffer(size);
                var base64 = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.encodeToBase64String(buffer);
                success(base64);
            })
        }
    });
}

function addimage() {

    Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromPathAsync("D:\\hello.PNG").then(
        function (file) {
            ConverToBase64(file, function (str) {
                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + str;
                document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(img);
            });
        }, function (error) {

        }
    );
}
```